# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child using Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-context

I am trying to use React's new Context api in my React Native application (using Expo). However I get an error. Please note, I only get this error when I try to abstract away the Context.Provider into a Component.

Here is my UserContext.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import { SecureStore } from 'expo';
import { AUTH_TOKEN, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL } from '../constants/config'

// Signed-in user context
const UserContext = React.createContext();

export class UserContextProvider extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    token: SecureStore.getItemAsync(AUTH_TOKEN) || "",
    firstName: SecureStore.getItemAsync(FIRST_NAME) || "",
    lastName: SecureStore.getItemAsync(LAST_NAME) || "",
    email: SecureStore.getItemAsync(EMAIL) || "",
    };
    this.setUserContext = this.setUserContext.bind(this);
}

setUserContext = (authToken, firstName, lastName, email) => {
    SecureStore.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken);
    SecureStore.setItem(FIRST_NAME, firstName);
    SecureStore.setItem(LAST_NAME, lastName);
    SecureStore.setItem(EMAIL, email);
    this.setState({
    authToken, firstName, lastName, email
    });
};

render() {
    const {children} = this.props;

    return (
    <UserContext.Provider
        value={{
        ...this.state,
        setUserContext: this.setUserContext,
        }}
    >
        // TODO: Render UserContext presentation component here

        <React.Fragment>
        {children}
        </React.Fragment>
    </UserContext.Provider>
    );
}
}

export const UserContextConsumer = UserContext.Consumer;
```

Here is part of my App.js code, where I use the UserContextProvider. Please note this is the root of my app:

```
import { UserContextProvider } from "./contexts/UserContext";

export default () => {
return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <UserContextProvider componentChildren={Root}>
        <Root/>
    </UserContextProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
);
}
```

I use the UserContextConsumer in one my screens (or components) in the following manner. Please note, the error is thrown when I navigate to the screen in which the below code resides:

```
import { UserContextConsumer } from '../contexts/UserContext';

.
.
.
<Text style={styles.textLink}>
    <UserContextConsumer>
    {context => {
        return context.token
    }}
    </UserContextConsumer>
</Text>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
in RCTText (at Text.js:202)
in Text (at LoginScreen.js:26)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:154)
in AnimatedComponent (at TouchableOpacity.js:247)
in TouchableOpacity (at LoginScreen.js:24)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at Form.js:10)
in Form (at connectStyle.js:384)
in Styled(Form) (at LoginScreen.js:18)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at LoginScreen.js:17)
in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:791)
in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:887)
in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareHOC.js:397)
in _class (at Content.js:125)
in Content (at connectStyle.js:384)
in Styled(Content) (at LoginScreen.js:15)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at Container.js:15)
in Container (at connectStyle.js:384)
in Styled(Container) (at LoginScreen.js:14)
in LoginScreen (at SceneView.js:9)
in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:483)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:154)
in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:51)
in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:42)
in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:26)
in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:507)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at screens.native.js:76)
in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:401)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at StackViewLayout.js:400)
in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
in withOrientation (at StackView.js:49)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at Transitioner.js:141)
in Transitioner (at StackView.js:19)
in StackView (at createNavigator.js:59)
in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:59)
in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
in NavigationContainer (at Root.js:24)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at Root.js:22)
in Root (at App.js:58)
in UserContextProvider (at App.js:57)
in ApolloProvider (at App.js:56)
in Unknown (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)

This error is located at:
in RCTText (at Text.js:202)
in Text (at LoginScreen.js:26)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:154)
in AnimatedComponent (at TouchableOpacity.js:247)
in TouchableOpacity (at LoginScreen.js:24)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at Form.js:10)
in Form (at connectStyle.js:384)
in Styled(Form) (at LoginScreen.js:18)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at LoginScreen.js:17)
in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:791)
in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:887)
in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareHOC.js:397)
in _class (at Content.js:125)
in Content (at connectStyle.js:384)
in Styled(Content) (at LoginScreen.js:15)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at Container.js:15)
in Container (at connectStyle.js:384)
in Styled(Container) (at LoginScreen.js:14)
in LoginScreen (at SceneView.js:9)
in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:483)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:154)
in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:51)
in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:42)
in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:26)
in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:507)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at screens.native.js:76)
in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:401)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at StackViewLayout.js:400)
in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
in withOrientation (at StackView.js:49)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at Transitioner.js:141)
in Transitioner (at StackView.js:19)
in StackView (at createNavigator.js:59)
in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:59)
in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
in NavigationContainer (at Root.js:24)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at Root.js:22)
in Root (at App.js:58)
in UserContextProvider (at App.js:57)
in ApolloProvider (at App.js:56)
in Unknown (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)

throwOnInvalidObjectType
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:9955:20
reconcileChildFibers
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:10650:37
reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:10749:52
reconcileChildren
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:10744:44
updateContextConsumer
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:11295:28
performUnitOfWork
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:14020:31
workLoop
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:14044:49
renderRoot
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:14070:23
performWorkOnRoot
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:14561:40
performWork
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:14493:32
performSyncWork
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:14473:22
batchedUpdates
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:14643:30
batchedUpdates
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FPasha%2Freact-native-projects%2Fexpo%2Fyumm%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles:6775:33
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent
AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=fal
```

Please let me know if you need additional information. Your help would be greatly appreciated. 


Thank you.

Comment: How do you export and use your `UserContextProvider` component?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added some information to the question. Essentially, I wrap the root of my app with UserContextProvider and then use UserContextConsumer in of my screens. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You are welcome, but still, I can't see how you export it? Do you export it properly and import it again?

Comment: I added the import statements, import { UserContextProvider } from "./contexts/UserContext"; and import { UserContextConsumer } from '../contexts/UserContext';.

Comment: The exports are done in the UserContext.js file.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the export part of the provider. You are doing it right. Let me dig it up a little bit. If I can find something, I'll comment or provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I don't how couldn't I see this at the first look but you are trying to render an object directly: `token`. Here:

```
<UserContextConsumer>
    {context => {
        return context.token
    }}
</UserContextConsumer>
```

So, you want to render a property of it maybe?

```
<UserContextConsumer>
    {context => {
        return context.token._40
    }}
</UserContextConsumer>
```

Or you can use it in other ways of course, but you can't render it directly.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, I was convinced that context.token was a String type but you are correct it was actually an Object type.